# Magento send new order mail when order is created but not paid

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, email, transactional-mail

My Magento eshop will send a new order email to my customer service email account if the customer after pressed the `Order` button **(then will pass to payment gateway)**, **how can i avoid Magento send a order email to the email account before the payment is made?**

**How can i send it ?**

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not an e-mail is sent is determined by payment method chosen. Usually there's a related option on payment method configuration (System > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods) so you should start by looking there.

Answer (score 1):

You could disable the order email and just send the customer the invoice which should be created when the payment is completed.

Comment: the web site still sending the order email order even i disable the order email

Comment: Check that they aren't enabled for the store view also as that may not be using the default settings?